# Facing problem in creating dynamic file upload control in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

Im creatng dynamic control of file upload so user can upload more than one file. But when i add more than 5 file upload control and submit the form. Error occured and shows

```
The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

what can be the issue?

Comment: Most likely your server has a setting for number of concurrent connections allowed from a single user (usually somewhere around 5). Is the upload script sending all of the files simultaneously or one by one? What upload script are you using?

Comment: im running it on my own system not on a server and yes im sending all files by once.